# Programmatically check if page requires authentication based on web.config settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, forms-authentication

I would like to know if there is a way to check if a page requies authentication based on the web.config settings. Basically if there is a node like this

```
  <location path="account">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

then I would like to check on any page if it requires authentication or not and to  return true if it is under the account directory. Is this possible?

Comment: Couldn't you just parse the web.config with the XmlDocument and look for the setting you're looking for? Or am I misunderstanding your intentions?

Comment: if asp.net does this already i'd rather not put additional overhead/startup time by reading the config again.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to access the web.config from your asp.net application?

Comment: I've read your comment but that doesn't answer the question. I'll rephrase: are you looking for a way to access the settings set in your web.config based on what ASP.NET has read?

Comment: yes. i was hoping there was some hidden property or method for doing it, like a Page.RequiredAuthentication property that I could get at.

Comment: Please rephrase your question to state something to that effect. No one can seem to figure out what you are asking for.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390719/determine-if-current-page-requires-authorization ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to create an anonymous identity (principal), and pass it into the `CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal` method. It will determine if the page is public, or requires authentication.

See code below:

```
var principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(String.Empty, String.Empty), new string[]{});
bool requiredAuthentication = UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath, principal, Request.HttpMethod);
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you checking the page that the user has requested? Its unlikely as the request will never get to the page. Check the url authorization workflow.

[image]

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/user-based-authorization-cs

Comment: you're premise is wrong. you're assuming the user never logged in. in that case they would be redirected to the login page (and never get to a page that needed authentication). if they are logged in then assume they can get to any page... i still want to determine on each page if it was required for them to login or not

Comment: OK, maybe on each page you could potentially use the UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal method passing in a anonymous user and checking the response? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.urlauthorizationmodule.checkurlaccessforprincipal.aspx

Comment: this works. I'll post the code in a separate answer in case anyone wants copy pasta. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused as to what you are asking exactly, but to use your web.config to enforce authentication on a page-for-page basis, you need something like this:

```
 <location path="Forms/Administration/Default.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow roles="Administrator, User, AdditionalUser" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

If you need to be more granular than that, you need to add the logic to your middle-tier and then check on page load or url request (if MVC).

Comment: "add the logic to your middle-tier"? What?

Comment: Which logic, and where is the middle tier? Neither are clear.

Comment: OK. . .all due respect, but I have never been asked "where is the middle-tier".  I guess I mean the one in the middle of the stack.  On the server. . .uh. . .in the middle.  And by "logic" I mean the logic required for sniffing out the page requested against the permissions required for access.  Perhaps I am missing something here.  I am originally from the Southeast US afterall. . .

Comment: Sure, but isn't this question (by definition) about logic in the middle-tier?