# Programmatically see if a webpage has anonymous access?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

Is there a way to programmatically tell if a page in my website has anonymous access?

The idea is that I want to check where the user is going and, if they aren't logged in and are going to a protected page then I want to just popup a div that they can use to login before redirecting them rather than taking them to the actual login page. (If they browse to a protected page from the address bar though it would still redirect them to the actual login page).

I just need a way to see if the link they are clicking on takes them to a protected page or not.

Comment: Think I just found a duplicate to my own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662922/programmatically-check-if-page-requires-authentication-based-on-web-config-setti

Answer (score 0):

Set the page up so it forces authentication (like your shopping cart example earlier). You then have the popup show up.

I actually don't like this approach architecturally, as you could be sending sensitive information to a user that is not logged in. This is why ASP.NET (MVC or WebForms) has a built in redirect. Yes, it does send the user to another page, but it stops them from getting content they are not authorized to use.

Unless you wire the information to not "paint in" until a user is authenticated, you should not rely on covering the information with a popup as a means of security, as a user can always utilize show source.

Comment: The idea is to pop up the login div on the unprotected page they are already on when they navigate to a protected page, then redirect them after successful login. I think I've figured a way to do this involving an ajax call to verify they were successfully logged in after the div closes. (And it would still send them to the full login page if they navigated to a protected page via the address bar).

Comment: And just to clarify, what I meant in the first sentence in my last comment by "when they navigate" was specifically when they navigate using a control or link I have on the page that will be able to display the popup before redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use authorization filters so as to avoid unauthorized or anonymous access to a specific function.