# How to add a class to locked pages in asp:Menu

Tags: asp.net, sitemap, aspmenu-control

I am binding a web.sitemap to an `asp:Menu`, and want to assign classes to the menu items that require a login to access.

I know that in the siteMap section of the web.config file, if I set `securityTrimmingEnabled="true"` that it will only show items available to that user (roles/logged out/logged in).  This is fine with me, but the users want to see these links.

So I am trying to make an indicator that these pages are locked, preferably adding a class to those links.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Per [this meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), removing things like "Hi" and "Thanks" from posts is pretty standard procedure.  I was not trying to deface your question in any way.

Comment: I understand, but I subscribe to RSolberg's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a custom [ITemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.itemplate.instantiatein.aspx) for the [DynamicItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.dynamicitemtemplate.aspx) property of the [Menu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.aspx). As alternative (I guess with less code but I never tried) you may attach to [MenuItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.menuitemdatabound.aspx) event.

Comment: Sounds good so far, but any idea on how I would catch whether a page requires the user be logged in?

Comment: Create your ITemplate (follow link for an example), attach in debug and watch what you get. The SiteMapNode has a method to check if it's accessible to current logged-in user or not.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to do this, I've tried the MenuItemDataBound method and the DataItems don't really have a property for if they are accessible or not.

As far as the ITemplate, I can't figure out how to create a custom one or get this method from the SiteMapNode.

Comment: Example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.itemplate.instantiatein.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I saw that.  Still don't understand.  I ended up using the MenuItemDataBound event along with this custom class that mocks an HttpRequest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390719/determine-if-current-page-requires-authorization  it's a bit messy but it works