# Azure ACS, WIF 3.5, Asp.Net 3.5 Custom Membership Provider and IsAuthenticated

Tags: azure, wif, custom-membershipprovider

Following the steps in this guide [Using Azure ACS](http://robbincremers.me/2012/02/22/using-windows-azure-access-control-service-to-provide-a-single-sign-on-experience-with-popular-identity-providers/) I have a working Azure ACS service configured & authenticating via Facebook, redirecting back to a website running on my development server.

On authentication success Azure ACS redirects back to my local development website and the IsAuthenticated flag is true, however I want to set the IsAuthenticated flag to true only if the email from the claim also exists in my local database, via a check/call to a custom MembershipProvider. If the email from the claim does not exist I want to redirect the client to a register page. Once registered and authenticated I would like to set the IsAuthenticated flag to true.

Currently once authenticated with Facebook and AzureACS, a user can request a secure page such as ViewAccountBalance.aspx, even though the account does not exist since out of the box IsAuthenticated flag to true. Interested to hear what others have done and what the best practice is.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make a clear difference between authentication and authorization. Since the user logged in through Facebook it means he's authenticated (you know who he is and where he comes from).

Now, if you want to restrict parts of the application based on a specific condition you're actually talking about authorization. You might consider combining roles with a simple HttpModule. Example: your HttpModule could verify which page the user is browsing. If the user accesses a page that requires an active profile, you could use the following code:

```
public class RequiresProfileHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.AuthorizeRequest += new EventHandler(OnAuthorize);
    }

    private void OnAuthorize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
        if (app.Request.Url.ToString().Contains("bla") && !app.Context.User.IsInRole("UsersWithProfile"))
            app.Response.Redirect("http://myapp/register.aspx");
    }
}
```

The only thing you'll need to take care of is to update the principal to make sure it has the role UsersWithProfile if the user filled in his email address.

This is just one of many possible solutions. If you're using ASP.NET MVC you could achieve the same result with global ActionFilters. Or, you could also try to work with the IClaimsPrincipal (add a claim if the user has a profile).

Comment: In OnInit() of Global.asax I added:

this.PostAcquireRequestState += (s, e) => SecurityHelper.PostAcquireRequestState();

Then within SecurityHelper.PostAcquireRequestState I have logic to check if a page is secured by standard FormsAuth, similar to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390719/determine-if-current-page-requires-authorization)

I also do a lookup via Membership.GetUser and check if account exists otherwise I redirect to a Register page.

Answer (score 0):

Sandrino is correct. You can use role based authorization (or more generally, claim based authorization). By default, ACS simply returns the claims issued by the identity providers to your relying party. For Facebook, it will return an email claim. However, you can configure ACS to create additional rules. For example, you can map particular users to a role whose value is administrator. Then ACS will also return this role claim to your relying party. Then you can use Sandrino’s suggestion to use role based authorization. You can also refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185915.aspx for more information.