# HttpModule endless redirect

Tags: asp.net, redirect, forms-authentication, httpmodule

I'm using an HttpModule to try and redirect users to the login page if they're not authenticated, but for some reason it's just endlessly redirecting the page without landing anywhere.

Here's the module:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

public class AuthenticationModule : IHttpModule
{
    public AuthenticationModule()
    {            
    }

    public string ModuleName 
    { 
        get
        {
            return "AuthenticationModule";
        }
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication app)
    {
        app.BeginRequest += (new EventHandler(Application_BeginRequest));
    }

    private void Application_BeginRequest(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = app.Context;
        HttpRequest request = context.Request;
        HttpResponse response = context.Response;

        if (!request.IsAuthenticated && !request.RawUrl.Contains(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

I don't recall having ever worked with HttpModules before, so I'm not sure what's not working.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

request.RawUrl is the URL I entered into the browser. Your check `request.RawUrl.Contains(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl)` is case sensitive.

Additionally there are no checks for ressources. So each request for images, css files etc. will redirect to login page. You need to check if authentication is required for the ressource being called.

*Edit (hit the save button to early)*

Additionally I would do it on `AuthenticateRequest`

Comment: OK, that makes sense. How might I check if authentication is required for each resource being loaded?

Comment: Either you do a simple string checks like `if (!Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Contains("css"))` or you use the UrlAuthorizationModule. See this link for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390719/determine-if-current-page-requires-authorization

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't seem to be working... still getting a redirect loop.

Comment: Are you sure that loginUrl is the requested url? I have seen situations where an error on loginUrl had occured which redirected the user to an error page that requires authentication. So from error page the user was redirected back to login page and the loop started from the beginning.

Comment: Turns out that the login page isn't the login *page.* It points to an `.asp`. file that just handles the authentication... The actual login page is a different `.aspx` file that actually accepts credentials. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Sorry but I am afraid that I can´t follow you. What is the login page and what is the actual login page? And what page is called (request.RawUrl)? Do you post your credentials from the login.aspx to a login.asp which then will authenticate the user?